# Spring authorization server authenticate for each client

Tags: spring-security, spring-session, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I'm trying to build an Identity Provider using Spring authorization-server that third party applications are going to use for FIM (federated identity management).

We want each OAuth client to require authentication (if a user tries to login with a different client they would need to authenticate for each client).

Out of the box the flow looks like this:

[image]

So there's 2 issues.

1. The `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint just checks whether or not the sessions principal is authenticated, it doesn't care or know which client the principal was meant for.
2. There's just a single `/login` endpoint, so during authentication it doesn't know which client is used.

My best bet here is that I should:

1. Make the `oauth2/authorize` endpoint redirection to `/login` include the query parameter `client_id`
2. Create a custom `AuthenticationFilter` that also adds the `client_id` to the User principal
3. Override the `authorizationRequestConverter` for the `oauth2/authorize` endpoint and validate that the client in the request is the same as the client stored on the authenticated principal

Am I missing anything or do anyone know of a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe I need to use multiple sessions in order to be able to auto authenticate users who login to the same client multiple times?

Comment: Spring Security has a `SecurityContext` that can represent only a single logged in user. There isn't an out of the box concept of two principals or two users. The question to ask for this scenario is: How do you represent a user who is logged in twice? I'd say your ideas of customizing are on the right track.

Comment: *We want each OAuth client to require authentication (if a user tries to login with a different client they would need to authenticate for each client).* That makes no sense, why should an user login again for each client? It is the same authorisation server and the same credentials. This is tedious for the user.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Ok, would it be possible to re-authenticate users every time regardless which client is used in some fairly simple way?

Comment: I tend to agree with @dur in that case, this would be a fairly poor user experience. However, I can give a quick example of how you could do this, yes.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I understand that it might sound a bit weird.
The reason is that this is only going to be used as an Identity Provider.
We will store a user with lots of attributes and then each client will need different attributes much like consent, but we need the consent flow to be separate from OAuth since we would like customers to be able to use either OAuth or SAML.
So the solution (for now atleast) is to have a separate service that authenticates the user, collects consent and builds a new user for that specific client with only the attributes from the consent.

Comment: The authorization server's login flow will poll the authentication service for the authenticated user (which will be different for each client).

Comment: If we didn't have to support both OIDC & SAML I would have went for the device code grant with a customized consent flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment, it seems one possibility is to simply require authentication every time, or at least every time an authorization is requested. In that case, you could clear out the authentication after the authorization code is issued to the client, using a `Filter`. This doesn't seem ideal and will result in a poor user experience, but may achieve your requirement.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        // ...

        // Add filter to remove the SecurityContext after successful authorization
        http.addFilterAfter(new RemoveSecurityContextOnAuthorizationFilter(), LogoutFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    private static final class RemoveSecurityContextOnAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        private SecurityContextHolderStrategy securityContextHolderStrategy =
                SecurityContextHolder.getContextHolderStrategy();

        private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler = new CompositeLogoutHandler(
                new CookieClearingLogoutHandler("JSESSIONID"),
                new SecurityContextLogoutHandler()
        );

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            try {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } finally {
                String locationHeader = response.getHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION);
                if (locationHeader != null) {
                    UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(locationHeader).build();
                    if (uriComponents.getQueryParams().containsKey("code")) {
                        Authentication authentication = this.securityContextHolderStrategy.getContext().getAuthentication();
                        this.logoutHandler.logout(request, response, authentication);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: I'm thinking that the RP should use the refresh token if the access token expires.
However, if the user logout from the RP we would like the user to re-authenticate.
In that case this solution should fit our requirements right?

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time following, so it's hard to say for certain. If you really just want to solve logging out from the RP, you can think about [RP-initiated logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html). To me, it didn't quite sound like that was your requirement based on the question description.

Comment: Hmm, well in that case the RP wouldn't need to do the RP initiated logout I guess.
I'm thinking that if we logout the user from the authorization server directly after the OAuth flow is finished, the RP should still be able to get a new access token if the initial access token is expired by using the refresh token.
If both the access token & the refresh token has expired we would like the user to authenticate again.
I mean, isn't that the purpose of the refresh token?
If we customize sessions to allow 1 session / client, that session should still be invalid if the refresh token expired?

Comment: I believe you're correct in all that, yes.

Comment: @StevenRiesenberg I have to make some big architectural decisions and that I would like to have a third party opinion on.
But it's way too much to explain in comments or in a question.
Are you open for that kind of consultation?
You would ofcourse be compensated for your time.

Comment: Thanks for thinking of me! But no, I would not be available for that type of engagement, sorry :(